# How to use jquery.notify in angular

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, notify

There is a jquery lib: notify.js. I want to use this in my Angular project.

I add the dependency `"@types/jquery.notify": "^1.5.0"`.

And then in my services, import jquery:

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

then use

```
$.notify({})
```

to define notify options.

The problem is I can't access notify on $.
Do I need to do other things to access that?

Comment: At the moment, it seems you've only added the dependency for the typescript typings, not the actual code. That said, there are other libraries that will do the same thing without needing jQuery as a dependency. Check out https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-toastr which is designed to be used with Angular

Comment: i just didn't display the code because that is not  related to this question. i need to use jquery.notify in angular. but don't know how to access that from $

Comment: Sorry, what I meant is, have you added jquery notify as a dependency as well as the `@types`?

Answer (score 0):

If the package is on npm then install it like this:

```
npm i --save jquery.notify
```

and then import it into the component you need it in.

I couldn't find it. So download the source for it and add it to angular.json like this:

```
"scripts": [
  "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
  "path/to/notify.js"
]
```

Then you should just be able to use it in your component without anything more needed. jQuery will need to be in your scripts section before notify.js